# Using --limit to specify groups and hosts in that group not working in Ansible

Tags: ansible, pattern-matching, limit, group

I want Ansible to run a playbook on specific hosts from specific groups.

Here is my inventory

```ini
[a]
10.10.10.10
11.11.11.11
dog.local.lab

[b]
10.10.10.11
cat.local.lab
moose.local.lab

[c]
10.10.10.12
wolf.local.lab
```

I want to run the playbook with this

```bash
ansible-playbook -i ./inventory.ini
  --limit a:10.10.10.10,a:11.11.11.11,b:10.10.10.11,b:moose.local.lab,c:wolf.local.lab
  -e foo=test
  -e bar=test2
  ./mypbook.yaml
```

But ansible keeps giving back these warnings:

> [WARNING]: Could not match supplied host pattern, ignoring: a:10.10.10.10
> [WARNING]: Could not match supplied host pattern, ignoring: a:11.11.11.11
> [WARNING]: Could not match supplied host pattern, ignoring: b:10.10.10.11
> [WARNING]: Could not match supplied host pattern, ignoring: b:moose.local.lab
> [WARNING]: Could not match supplied host pattern, ignoring: c:wolf.local.lab
> ERROR! Specified inventory, host pattern and/or --limit leaves us with no hosts to target.

Why? am I using the `--limit` incorrectly?

Comment: I guess you misread the documentation [`--limit 'all:!host1'`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/inventory_guide/intro_patterns.html#patterns-and-ad-hoc-commands) as being _not the host1 that is part of all_; when in fact the colon or comma are the same. _You can use either a comma (`,`) or a colon (`:`) to separate a list of hosts. The comma is preferred when dealing with ranges and IPv6 addresses._ And the example limit in the documentation actually means _run on the group all **and** exclude host1_.

Comment: I just read this. So basically what I am trying to do is not supported at all? or is there some other way to accomplish what I want / a plugin to do it?

Comment: Is there something preventing you to just list the hosts? I.e. `--limit 10.10.10.10,11.11.11.11,10.10.10.11,moose.local.lab,wolf.local.lab`. I guess you might have an issue with variable hidden behind this that you are not showing in here, is it?

Answer (score 1):

Q: ***"Am I using the --limit incorrectly?"***

A: Yes. The ansible-playbook man says:

> -l 'SUBSET', --limit 'SUBSET' further limit selected hosts to an additional pattern

See the [patterns](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.8/user_guide/intro_patterns.html) the man is talking about. There is no such pattern that limits a host to a group e.g. `a:10.10.10.10`. In fact, it wouldn't make sense to create such a limitation because it doesn't matter what group a host comes from once you put it into this list. For example, given the inventory

```ini
shell> cat inventory.ini 
[a]
10.10.10.10
11.11.11.11
dog.local.lab

[b]
10.10.10.11
cat.local.lab
moose.local.lab

[c]
10.10.10.12
wolf.local.lab
```

The playbook

```yaml
shell> cat mypbook.yml
- hosts: all
  tasks:
    - debug:
        var: ansible_play_hosts_all
      run_once: true
```

works as expected

```yaml
shell> ansible-playbook -i inventory.ini --limit 10.10.10.10,11.11.11.11,10.10.10.11,moose.local.lab,wolf.local.lab mypbook.yml

  ...

  ansible_play_hosts_all:
  - 10.10.10.10
  - 11.11.11.11
  - 10.10.10.11
  - moose.local.lab
  - wolf.local.lab

  ...
```